# Merging Multiple Paths

Tags: qgis, google-earth, merge

Alright, I'm going to start by using Google Earth terminology because that's where the original need for a solution came up.  I have multiple paths (54) that I want to merge into a single path.

Using QGIS I converted to .shp file, but it still maintained the 'feature subset'.  So next question - within QGIS does anyone know of any easy way to merge the features of a single shp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Ftools plugin. Choose singleparts to multipart and select your shapefile:

[image]

Comment: Or `Singleparts to multipart`?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I solved my problem by writing a utility in C.

It expects a KML with all your path segments in proper order and only segments to be merged. It will flip segments as required for a best fit, producing a KML with the combined path.

It can be found on Github at the URL below.

https://github.com/mgemeny/KMLpathMerge

I hope this helps,

Mike